# boost wifi strength and speed in multi-user environment

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

My girlfriend lives in a flat in a multi-occupancy building where all occupants share the signal from one router in the main office. She seems to be very much on the end of the foodchain - the signal is often so weak her Chromebook doesn't think it's connected at all! You have to try website addresses multiple times and FINALLY it MIGHT connect - if you're lucky! How would you boost the signal in her apartment? She cannot move the router as it is fixed in the Central Offices of the flats and their computers all use it too. Her Chromebook does not have an Ethernet socket.

We've heard of signal extenders but some sites say they're great, others that they're useless and we don't know which to believe. And great or not, there's a HEWGE price range from £20-ish to over £1000 - are the cheap ones (we can afford those!) any good?

She's approx. 70 feet from the router physically if that means anything - I know you can sit right next to a router and still have a slow connection cos I've done it!

Yours hopefully

Ulrichburke

Comment: Does the _flat_ have Ethernet sockets? (the Chromebook itself doesn't need to, as long as you can get Ethernet somewhere reasonably nearby)

Comment: There might be some walls or floors that weaken reception. If she's using 5GHz, she could try the stronger 2.4 GHz. Otherwise, an extender/booster/repeater could help, but it would need to be positioned in-between the main router and the flat.